# separate each postfix with its own maillog?

Tags: postfix

I have 2 postfix on my server ( instance postfix ), I want to separate each postfix  with its own maillog?

Answer (score 2):

Postfix uses syslog to write its log messages.

You can easily use the [multi_instance_name](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#multi_instance_name) or [syslog_name](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#syslog_name) to make Postfix log with a unique name and then use your syslogd's capabilities to write the messages of each instance to a separate file.